# Get The Title Of An MP3 File After It Has Been Uploaded By Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, mp3

I set up an upload form in Django and everything is working perfectly fine.  I was just wondering how to access the title of an mp3 file after it has been uploaded, however.  I will be allowing users to upload audio tracks and would like to automatically generate the song titles instead of having the users type them in themselves.

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You use the `filename` attribute of the object:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: So that returns example.mp3 but what I want is the name that would come up if you were to play it in iTunes for example.

Comment: It returns the uploaded file name, if you upload **Adelle - Set Fire To The Rain.mp3** thats what it will show, if you want it to display something else you'll have to change it manually in a form with the same attribute